# how to do combination for extra column view with maximum value 2

Tags: haskell

**Update2** : is it possible to have dynamic number of type in return of function for 3^2, 4^2, 5^2, ... 10^2, so far i have to hard code this, and even if add back this, 
i feel not a full combination

```
comb0 :: [(Int, Int, Int)]
comb0 = do
   a <- [0,1,2]
   b <- [0,1,2]
   return (a, b, 2 - max a b)

comb :: [(Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)]
comb = do
   a1 <- [0]
   a2 <- [0,1]
   a3 <- [0]
   a4 <- [0,1] 
   a5 <- [0,1]
   a6 <- [0]
   a7 <- [0]
   a8 <- [0]
   a9 <- [0]
   return (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9)
```

**Update1** : i thought a stupid way but may have full combination

assume output is [0;1;0] input column 1 [0;0;1] input column 2[0;1;0]

since input 1 and input 2 first row is 0, so do not care first 0 in output

and then 2 minus [1;0] become [1;2] and then

we see that there are two rows, so make two for loop

for i in 0..1 do

```
 for j in 0..2 do
```

combinations become [0;0] , [0;1], [0; 2],  [1;0] , [1; 1], [1; 2]

add back to [1;0] become [1+0; 0+0], [1+0; 0+1], [1+0; 0+2], [1+1; 0+1]... etc then glue then back to the table

how to write this in simple way in haskell?

**Original question:**
if only return (a,b), the input is correct for logic table

this problem is using value 2, you can say that it is 3 valued, 
when i calculated for 5 valued, my computer calculated is slow in c#
waiting for long time, still not finish, i expect to increase value 
as many as possible, hope haskell can be faster in this

expect to add output column to this,
i use ((a,b), max(a,b)) as the starting point, and then add one to third 
column which is output until reach 2 and recursively run and save each combination in list written in F#, output 12 combinations outputs, but i feel that there is some
missing, not full combinations, expect to use haskell do the same things to see full combinations of this and save into text file and moreover counting how many combinations it have

if except first row 0, 0 keep output 0 too

```
comb :: [(Int, Int, Int)]
comb = do
   b <- [0,1,2]
   a <- [0,1,2]
   return (a,b, max a b)

comb2 :: [(Int, Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
comb2 x = do
   c <- [0,1,2]
   return (fst x, fst snd x, c + snd snd x)
```

[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, main.o )

```
main.hs:67:19:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int'
                with actual type `(Int, Int) -> (Int, Int)'
    In the return type of a call of `max'
    Probable cause: `max' is applied to too few arguments
    In the expression: max (a, b)
    In the first argument of `return', namely `((a, b), max (a, b))'

comb :: [((Int, Int), Int)]
comb = do
   b <- [0,1,2]
   a <- [0,1,2]
   return ((a,b), max(a,b))

  mapM_ print comb
```

F# code

```
let MakeColumn(input : List<int> , m1 : int , m2 : int, numberofvalue : int) : List<int>=
    let mutable zero1 = 0
    for i in 0..(m1-1) do
        for j in 0..(m2-1) do
            input.Add(zero1)
        zero1 <- zero1 + 1
        if zero1 >= numberofvalue then
            zero1 <- 0
    input

let mutable col1_3 : List<int> = new List<int>()
let mutable col2_3 : List<int> = new List<int>()
let mutable col3_3 : List<int> = new List<int>()
let mutable col1_2 : List<int> = new List<int>()
let mutable col2_2 : List<int> = new List<int>()
let mutable col3_2 : List<int> = new List<int>()
let Radix = 3
let mutable totalrows = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(float 2, float Radix))
col1_3 <- MakeColumn(col1_3, totalrows, 1, 2)
col2_3 <- MakeColumn(col2_3, totalrows/2, 2, 2)
col3_3 <- MakeColumn(col3_3, totalrows/4, 4, 2)
col1_2 <- MakeColumn(col1_2, totalrows/2, 1, 2)
col2_2 <- MakeColumn(col2_2, totalrows/4, 2, 2)
let debugtotalrows = totalrows
let debugcol1_3 = col1_3
let debugcol2_3 = col2_3
let debugcol3_3 = col3_3
let debugcol1_2 = col1_2
let debugcol2_2 = col2_2
let debugcol3_2 = col3_2
let mutable col1_3a : List<int> = new List<int>()
let mutable col2_3a : List<int> = new List<int>()
let debugcol1_3a = MakeColumn(col1_3a, 9/3, 3, 3)
let debugcol2_3a = MakeColumn(col2_3a, 9, 1, 3)
for i in 0..(col1_3.Count-1) do
    Console.WriteLine(col1_3.[i].ToString()+","+col2_3.[i].ToString())


let MinimumCovering(col1 : List<int>, col2 : List<int>)=
    let OutputBits = new List<int>()
    for i in 0..(col1.Count-1) do
        OutputBits.Add(Math.Max(col1.[i], col2.[i]))
    OutputBits

let MinimumCoveringList(col1 : List<int>, col2 : List<int>)=
    let mutable OutputBits = []
    for i in 0..(col1.Count-1) do
        OutputBits <- Math.Max(col1.[i], col2.[i]) :: OutputBits
    let finaloutput = List.rev OutputBits
    finaloutput

let NumberOfNonMaximumForCovering(col1 : List<int>)=
    let mutable count = 0
    for i in 0..(col1.Count-1) do
        if col1.[i] <> 2 then
            count <- count + 1
    count

let rec AllCombinationOfBasicOutput(NumberOfNonMaximumValue : int, MinimumCoveringOutputParam : int list, numberofloops : int, maximumvalue : int, finaloutput : Dictionary<int list, int list> byref)=
    let mutable newoutputs = new Dictionary<int list, int list>()
    if numberofloops-1 >= 0 then
        newoutputs <- new Dictionary<int list, int list>()
    for i in 0..(NumberOfNonMaximumValue-1) do 
        let mutable newoutput = []
        for j in 0..(MinimumCoveringOutputParam.Length-1) do //change one row at each time
            if i = j then
                if MinimumCoveringOutputParam.[j] + 1 < maximumvalue then
                    newoutput <- MinimumCoveringOutputParam.[j] + 1 :: newoutput
                else
                    newoutput <- MinimumCoveringOutputParam.[j] :: newoutput
            else
                newoutput <- MinimumCoveringOutputParam.[j] :: newoutput
        let newoutput5 = List.rev newoutput
        if finaloutput.ContainsKey(newoutput5) = false then
            finaloutput.Add(newoutput5, newoutput5)            
        if numberofloops-1 >= 0 then
            finaloutput <- AllCombinationOfBasicOutput(NumberOfNonMaximumValue, newoutput5, numberofloops - 1, maximumvalue, &finaloutput)
    finaloutput

let MinimumCoveringOutput = MinimumCovering(debugcol1_3a, debugcol2_3a)
let MinimumCoveringOutputList = MinimumCoveringList(debugcol1_3a, debugcol2_3a)         
let NumberOfNonMaximum = NumberOfNonMaximumForCovering(MinimumCoveringOutput)
let mutable newoutputs3 = new Dictionary<int list, int list>()   
let comboutputs = AllCombinationOfBasicOutput(NumberOfNonMaximum, MinimumCoveringOutputList, NumberOfNonMaximum, 3, &newoutputs3)
let ChangeIntListToListInt(m : int list) : List<int> =
    let result = new List<int>()
    for i in 0..(m.Length-1) do
        result.Add(m.[i])
    result

for aa in comboutputs.Keys do
    let newaa = ChangeIntListToListInt(aa)
    WriteTableMultipleValuedLogic(debugcol1_3a, debugcol2_3a,newaa, "E:/martintonic.txt")
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText("E:/martintonic.txt", "*****\r\n")
```

expect to compare the output below to see whether below is full combinations

```
0,0=1
0,1=1
0,2=2
1,0=1
1,1=1
1,2=2
2,0=2
2,1=2
2,2=2
*****
0,0=2
0,1=1
0,2=2
1,0=1
1,1=1
1,2=2
2,0=2
2,1=2
2,2=2
*****
0,0=2
0,1=2
0,2=2
1,0=1
1,1=1
1,2=2
2,0=2
2,1=2
2,2=2
*****
0,0=2
0,1=1
0,2=2
1,0=2
1,1=1
1,2=2
2,0=2
2,1=2
2,2=2
*****
0,0=2
0,1=2
0,2=2
1,0=2
1,1=1
1,2=2
2,0=2
2,1=2
2,2=2
*****
0,0=1
0,1=2
0,2=2
1,0=1
1,1=1
1,2=2
2,0=2
2,1=2
2,2=2
*****
0,0=1
0,1=2
0,2=2
1,0=2
1,1=1
1,2=2
2,0=2
2,1=2
2,2=2
*****
0,0=1
0,1=1
0,2=2
1,0=2
1,1=1
1,2=2
2,0=2
2,1=2
2,2=2
*****
0,0=0
0,1=2
0,2=2
1,0=1
1,1=1
1,2=2
2,0=2
2,1=2
2,2=2
*****
0,0=0
0,1=2
0,2=2
1,0=2
1,1=1
1,2=2
2,0=2
2,1=2
2,2=2
*****
0,0=0
0,1=1
0,2=2
1,0=1
1,1=1
1,2=2
2,0=2
2,1=2
2,2=2
*****
0,0=0
0,1=1
0,2=2
1,0=2
1,1=1
1,2=2
2,0=2
2,1=2
2,2=2
*****
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `max a b`, not `max (a,b)`. The former passes two arguments, the latter passes just one -- a pair `(a,b)`.

Comment: how about combination in column view

Answer (score 1):

as you asked me - you can get the `comb2` compiling with:

```
comb2 :: [(Int, Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
comb2 xs = do
   (a,b,c) <- xs
   d <- [0,1,2]
   return (a, b, c+d)
```

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do with the `fst` and `snd` stuff but it looks a bit like LISPs `car` & `cdr` - but those would rather be `head` and `tail` and obvious only work for lists - not for tuples ;)

btw: as you seem to know a bit F# - there you would do it in a similar faction - those `mutable` values are really anti-idiomatic F# ;)

```
> let comb2 xs = seq {
-    for (a,b,c) in xs do
-    for d in 0..2 do
-    yield (a,b,c+d) };;

val comb2 : xs:seq<'a * 'b * int> -> seq<'a * 'b * int>
```

as you can see instead of the `do` block you can just use an `seq` *expression*