# Couldn't match expected type `((Int, Int, Int) -> Int, b5)'

Tags: haskell

do not know why debug many times still have error even if explicit declare type
int, do not know where do b0, a0, b2 come from

```
 ghc -o hello main.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, main.o )

main.hs:92:10:
    Couldn't match expected type `(Int, b0)'
                with actual type `(Int, Int, Int)'
    In the first argument of `fst', namely `x'
    In the first argument of `(==)', namely `fst x'
    In the first argument of `(&&)', namely `fst x == a1'

main.hs:92:25:
    Couldn't match expected type `((Int, Int, Int) -> Int, b1)'
                with actual type `(a0, b2) -> b2'
    In the first argument of `fst', namely `snd'
    In the first argument of `(==)', namely `fst snd x'
    In the second argument of `(&&)', namely `fst snd x == b1'

main.hs:93:12:
    Couldn't match expected type `(a1, (Int, Int, Int) -> Int)'
                with actual type `(a2, b3) -> b3'
    In the first argument of `snd', namely `snd'
    In the expression: snd snd x
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      if fst x == a1 && fst snd x == b1 then snd snd x else 0

main.hs:97:10:
    Couldn't match expected type `(Int, b4)'
                with actual type `(Int, Int, Int)'
    In the first argument of `fst', namely `x'
    In the first argument of `(==)', namely `fst x'
    In the first argument of `(&&)', namely `fst x == a1'

main.hs:97:25:
    Couldn't match expected type `((Int, Int, Int) -> Int, b5)'
                with actual type `(a3, b6) -> b6'
    In the first argument of `fst', namely `snd'
    In the first argument of `(==)', namely `fst snd x'
    In the second argument of `(&&)', namely `fst snd x == b1'

main.hs:98:12:
    Couldn't match expected type `(a4, (Int, Int, Int) -> Int)'
                with actual type `(a5, b7) -> b7'
    In the first argument of `snd', namely `snd'
    In the expression: snd snd x
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      if fst x == a1 && fst snd x == b1 then
          snd snd x
      else
          firstlogic xs a1 b1
```

this code mainly to use generated logic table as a function to return the value
of the logic after input two parameters
code:

```
comb0 :: [(Int, Int, Int)]
comb0 = do
   a <- [0,1,2]
   b <- [0,1,2]
   return (a, b, max a b)

firstlogic :: [(Int, Int, Int)] -> Int -> Int -> Int
firstlogic [] a1 b1 = 0
firstlogic [x] a1 b1 = do
  if fst x == a1 && fst snd x == b1
  then snd snd x
  else
    0
firstlogic (x:xs) a1 b1 = do
  if fst x == a1 && fst snd x == b1
  then snd snd x 
  else
    firstlogic xs a1 b1

main :: IO()
main = do 
  print firstlogic comb0 1 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dietrich pointed you already to the main problem I thought I could help you out a bit more.

This one will compile and I think it does what you want (although I am not sure):

```
comb0 :: [(Int, Int, Int)]
comb0 = do
   a <- [0,1,2]
   b <- [0,1,2]
   return (a, b, max a b)

firstlogic :: [(Int, Int, Int)] -> Int -> Int -> Int
firstlogic [] _ _ = 0
firstlogic ((x1,x2,x3):xs) a1 b1
  | x1==a1 && x2==b1 = x3
  | otherwise = firstlogic xs a1 b1


main :: IO ()
main = 
  print $ firstlogic comb0 1 2
```

the reason why I am not sure if it does what you want is that I don't understand what you are trying to do - first you take every combination of `[0,1,2]` with itself, add the maximum of the two parts and then you search for a certain combination in `firstlogic` and return the `max` again

If I am right this function does exactly the same but does not need `comb0` and has no need to search:

```
firstlogic :: Int -> Int -> Int
firstlogic = max
```

(ok: what it does not is check if both of the inputs are in `[0,1,2]` - but you can easily add this)

Comment: could you help me one more in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30662811/how-to-do-combination-for-extra-column-view-with-maximum-value-2

Comment: I just did - but you should really try to figure it out yourself - also (I hope you don't mind me asking): Do you try to learn FP, F# and Haskell all at the same time? If so I would drop one of the languages for now and only concentrate on the FP parts - the other language will be easy to learn after (well if it's Haskell the basics will be easy to learn at least)

Answer (score 4):

The function `fst` takes a pair, not a triple.

```
fst :: (a, b) -> a
```

You need a different function, `fst3`:

```
fst3 :: (a, b, c) -> a
```

You can write this function, or you can use pattern matching / switch expressions.

The appearance of `fst snd x` also makes no sense, because `fst` only takes one argument, and `x` has type `(Int, Int, Int)` anyway.  Not sure what you're trying to accomplish here.  Try using pattern matching or switch expressions.

This is not intended to be exhaustive.  There are other problems in the code.